# Network Disabled Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, networking

I recently installed the latest version. I'm unable to get network connectivity using WiFi. When I click on it, it says Network Disabled. I did a `cd /etc` and tried `init.d/networking start` and got:

```
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted..........also use the Start (8) Utility.
```

I'm lost now. Any assistance to be able to use this on a **Dell Inspirion Mini** would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise, I'm back to that evil dual boot using a very slow version of Windows...Yuk!!

1st Command

```
0:  compal-wifi:  Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked:  no
      Hard Blocked:  no
1:  compal-bluetooth:  Bluetooth
      Soft blocked:  no
      Hard blicked:  no
2:  phy0:  Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked:  no
     Hard blocked:  no
```

2nd Command

```
03:00.0 Network Controller [0280] :  Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Also ran sudo service networking restart.

```
Restart:  Unknown instance.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these two terminal commands: rfkill list all and also: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Try running sudo service networking restart

Comment: compal-wifi: Wireless LAN